# raspberry pi3 + fingerprint

Tags: rpi.gpio, pi-3b+, sensor

I'm looking for a way to connect fingerprint scanner with raspberry pi3 using `python`. I'd like to use only `gpio` or `hat` (not `usb`) interface. I'm searching for a while without figured out, so I've decided to ask. Are there any fingerprint to fit my case?

- EDIT

I want to achieve biometric attendance system (fingerprint + rfid sensor)
something like that, but I really prefer `GPIO` over `USB` interface (because of physical space in my case)

this is another project i've found:
[image: example]

video of this project:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FLe8VO5jXs

Moreover, I really prefer a fingerprint like this module, because I have to fix it to a box printed in 3d:

[image: fingerprint]

Comment: Ah, there are finger print readers using UART.

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: Ah, I never suggest any commercial products in this forum.  I can only tell you that I almost never buy things from expensive shops like AdaFruit, because I am a poor hobbyist and cannot afford them.  Actually I have never bought anything from AliExpress, because TaoBao is even cheaper.

Comment: Not sure what search queries you where using but, Googling for `fingerprint scanner GPIO or serial similar:stackexchange` resulted in finding a related [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/79322/8651). I'd suggest _more research_ and editing your question to include what _flavor_ of RPi you're going to attempt this on as there may be some differences between RPis that could lead to headaches. And is there a reason why USB is being avoided for this use case?

Comment: thanks @S0AndS0. The reason is because of space (physical space) . I've edited my answer, thanks again for your useful tips

Comment: Excellent edit @andreah, and I hope someone with more direct knowledge is able to provide an answer. One thing to keep in mind though is if you're willing to sacrifice one of the USB ports it may be possible to solder directly to it, though that should really only be considered if ya cannot find a compatible _hat_. One questions too; have ya considered how you're going to keep the data and device secure?... I see many _bad days_ in the future if an adversary where to _scrape_ all that data about those in attendance.

Comment: I was thinking of recording the fingerprint on the RFID card (as well as the user's ID). So I don't need to save the fingerprint in a database. Honestly, however, I have to think more about it